# I need help making a little window for a program im making. It seems to not be working

Tags: python, tkinter

It for some reason doesn't give me any output or even any errors when I run it. Does anybody have a solution to the problem?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

a1 = Label(window, text="Title")
a1.grid(row=0, column=0)

a2 = Label(window, text="Author")
a2.grid(row=0, column=2)

a3 = Label(window, text="Year")
a3.grid(row=1, column=0)

a4 = Label(Window, text="ISBN")
a4 .grid(row=1, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this?  I would expect it to produce an error due to `column` being misspelled.

Comment: @Ronald, thanks for the help! I would upvote your comments if I had the reputation to

Answer (score 0):

when I ran it, it gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/your_name/Desktop/program_name.py", line 6, in <module>
    a1.grid(row=0, column=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2484, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-column": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
>>>
```

fixed code

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

a1 = Label(window, text="Title")
a1.grid(row=0, column=0)

a2 = Label(window, text="Author")
a2.grid(row=0, column=2)

a3 = Label(window, text="Year")
a3.grid(row=1, column=0)

a4 = Label(window, text="ISBN")
a4.grid(row=1, column=2)




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: And the space behind a4 .grid

Answer (score 0):

I got multiple errors, so let's tackle them all. While typing I saw the comment above pop up, so, yes:

```
Window -> window  # a4
a4 .grid -> a4.grid   # for consistency, I was pointed out that this is not a real error
```

Comment: `a4 .grid`, with that unnecessary space, isn't any sort of error.

Comment: Holy smoke! ;-) You are right, I really did not know that. Learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

The errors in your code are as follows (as comments after the errors):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

a1 = Label(window, text="Title")
a1.grid(row=0, column=0)    #spelling of "column" is wrong

a2 = Label(window, text="Author")
a2.grid(row=0, column=2)    #spelling of "column" is wrong

a3 = Label(window, text="Year")
a3.grid(row=1, column=0)    #spelling of "column" is wrong

a4 = Label(Window, text="ISBN")   #you have defined **w**indow= Tk() and used 'w' as uppercase here
a4 .grid(row=1, column=2)    #spelling of "column" is wrong

window.mainloop()
```

I hope you saw and understood the mistakes you were making.